# date conversion / extraction issue between mssql > php > mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date, object

This is my code and the output is right after that...

```
$PDate = $row['PDate'];  
//row is tapping into ms-sql date field. 
//and the ms-sql data field has a value like this for the PDate; 
//07/12/2001
$PDate = $PDate->date;
echo "<h1>[", $PDate , "]</h1>";
echo "<h1>[", var_dump($row['PDate']) , "]</h1>";
echo "<h1>[", serialize($row['PDate']) , "]</h1><hr>";
```

the output is as follows. And my question is embedded in the output.

```
[]      ??? WHY IS THIS BLANK? WHY IS THIS NOT 2001-12-07 00:00:00? 

[object(DateTime)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2001-12-07 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "America/Los_Angeles" } ]

[O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:19:"2001-12-07 00:00:00";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:19:"America/Los_Angeles";}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of var_dump indicate that you're working with a DateTime object.  If you want the date in a format that it can be transmitted to output or another database, you'd probably want to try working with $PDate (or $row['PDate']) as a DateTime object.

For instance:

```
echo $PDate->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$PDate` stores the result from the table. So why do you redefine the variable to a variable in an object that doesn't exist. Have you tried just using `$row['date']` instead of assigning it to `$PDate`?

Comment: If I do that I get this at the time insert; Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in sql.php on line 379